# How to use LINQPad with SharePoint 2013 REST service (/_api)?

Tags: 2013, rest

It is working just fine with `/_vti_bin/ListData.svc`, but I can't create connection for `/_api URI`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't used LINQPad but I assume it's because _api doesn't expose metadata.

http://www.odata.org/documentation/overview#ServiceMetadataDocument